# Drupal 7 REST services - Suppress API output of NULL

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-services

I've an API service callback function which ties up with its own module template to give an HTML output. As per my understanding, default content type of API output is `application/json`, so I had to override it manually to `text/html`.

However, I'm still getting a `null` output always no matter whatever I try. How can I suppress this unwanted `null` output?

---

### `custom_module.module`

```
function api_callback_function($a) {
  if (!headers_sent()) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  }
  print theme('custom_template_name_alias', array(
    'b' => $a
  ));
  return;
}

function custom_module_theme() {
  $themes = array(
    'custom_template_name_alias' => array(
      'template' => 'something-only', // name of template file, sans file extension
      'variables' => array(
        'b' => NULL
      ),
    )
  );
  return $themes;
}
```

---

### `something-only.tpl.php`

```
<?php
$c = $variables['b'];
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module');
global $base_url;
?>
<!doctype html><html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- HEAD related HTML code comes here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Current value of variable 'b' = <?php echo $c; ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: How many times `api_callback_function` is calling? I suppose, it prints your template twice.

Comment: @A.Mikhailov - nope, it's called only once, when I'm initiating the API call.
Had I returned the `theme` instead of printing it in `api_callback_function`, then it would have called twice.

Comment: 1) Is anything changed if you replace `return` by `die()`? 2) Try to dump $a value directly in api callback.

Comment: @A.Mikhailov - Well, well, seems like you nailed it, buddy, Thank you!  
1. Yes, it works just like the way I would've wanted.  
2. I wouldn't do that since I'm anyways using the `$a` value in the theme via the template variable `b`.  
Can you please post your answer right away? I want to mark you who gave the correct answer.  
Also just a thought - is it possible to end the function definition in a proper way instead of just putting a `die()` or `exit`?

Comment: If I want to print result for AJAX requests I using `die()` instead of `drupal_exit()`. But idk is it proper way to Your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `return` to `die()` in `api_callback_function`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Although it's quirky, but it works well.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving No problems. Perhaps you will find more neat solution later)

Comment: Looking forward to that, Cheers!